# How do I convert a PDF to a text file and preserve the format of the PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, text, file-conversion

Hello I want to convert a PDF file to text file. I am converting the PDF file to text file. But it doesn't preserves the format of text which is exactly in PDF file.

Please help me.

Comment: Why would you like to do this? maybee you are on the wrong way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A text file by itself cannot contain formatting.**

You cannot preserve formatting in a plain text file because it only contains text.  There could be HTML markup inside the text file, but then I would call this an HTML file.  Otherwise, you should be trying to convert it into a rich text format (RTF), Microsoft Word, OpenOffice, or some other document type instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

```
File f = new File(fileName);
        if (!f.isFile()) {  
            return null;  
        } 


        try {
            parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(f));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }  

        try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();  
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
           /* pdfStripper.setStartPage(2); 
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(3);*/  
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document.");  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            try {  
                   if (cosDoc != null) cosDoc.close();  
                   if (pdDoc != null) pdDoc.close();  
               } catch (Exception e1) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            return null;  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

PDFBox will help you for this it may loose some formatting **as Erick Robertson said**

refer [PDF Text Parser: Converting PDF to Text in Java using PDFBox](http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/01/convert-pdf-text-parser-java-api-pdfbox.html)

Comment: Link doesn't work or more exactly: gives me a popup warning about trojan virus.

Comment: it is 10 year old answer link may not be available now.